# How do you display multiple files in a gui field on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, text

Using a Windows file dialog if multiple files are selected they are double quote limited and separated by a space as follows:

```
"C:\MusicMatched2\Gold Greatest Hits" "C:\MusicMatched2\The Trials of Van Occupanther"
```

But is this what OSX does as well, I can't seem to find an example with applications on my mac, but I need to do the correct way to display multiple filenames in a simple textfield of a Gui application on a mac.

Comment: You mean in an NSSavePanel or NSOpenPanel? Or do you just want to display a text list of file paths in a view in a window?

Comment: @uchuugaka  I think I mean NSOpenPanel, Im just looking for an example of what it should look like to user rather than an implementation, i.e is it same or different to WIndows

Comment: These interactions on OS X are very different from Windows. In the general case, this list you speak of doesn't happen. But nothing would stop you from creating something like that. It just might not make sense without a use-case

Comment: So there is nothing that lets you select multiple files folders and then present the selection to you ?

Comment: With an NSOpenPanel, you can do multiple selections, but only from what is currently visible. The flow is quite different from what you may be familiar with. You can add accessory views to it and display things there, but it doesn't work like Windows. You would need to do some customization or subclassing to get that, or run the panel multiple times, and then in your main (non-modal) window display the list. Use your Mac, get familiar with it, don't try to make it do things Windows does, users will understand.

Comment: You really just need to start playing with NSOpenPanel, it's pretty easy and its completion handler includes an NSArray of NSURLs for selections.

Comment: @uchuugaka Well this is written in Java so Im not actually using NSpanel or anything, I was hoping to just try an existing application on my Mac to see how this would work

Comment: Thus should move to chat but the Java part should be part of the question really as it presents a very different situation depending on the Java frameworks in use.

Comment: its not a technical question about java I'm just asking for an example of how an application deals with multiple files/folder being selected.

Answer (score 3):

You're not supposed to present file paths to the user on the Mac. First of all, the user's view of the file hierarchy is not the same as the low-level view represented by paths. The Finder and the standard file dialogs maintain a consistent illusion of a file system hierarchy which doesn't actually exist. For example, each volume is a separate root in the Finder, but volumes other than the boot volume appear under /Volumes in the Unix file system. The Finder has a Computer view which has no representation in the Unix file system. Often, the Finder will represent the user's home folder as a independent root, even though the user can also usually get there from (boot drive) > Users > (user's account name).

There are other subtleties. For example, the names of various folders can be localized for display. However, they are never localized at the Unix path level. So, there will always be a folder whose path is /Applications, but it would be displayed as "Programme" on a German system.

Your app should not pierce this veil and expose users to the Unix-style paths of files.

There are APIs for obtaining the "display name" of a file or the array of display components to display (which is not the same as obtaining the display name of each element of the path). You could concatenate the display components with some separator string to make a text string for a path, but there's not really a standard separator.

The more correct approach is to use a "[path control](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Controls/Controls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000359-SW112)" ([`NSPathControl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSPathControl_class/Reference/Reference.html)). This is a GUI widget that displays a file's location in the standard manner, with the standard separator, etc.

If you need to display multiple file locations, you might consider doing what the Finder does when you do a search. It shows the matches in a list and as you select them it shows the location of each in a path control below the list. You could also show a table with the display names in one column and a path control showing the location in another column.

Answer (score 1):

A typical use of `NSOpenPanel` looks like this

```
-(void)showFileSelector {

    NSOpenPanel *openpanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

    [openpanel setDelegate:self];

    [openpanel setCanCreateDirectories:NO];

    [openpanel setCanChooseFiles:YES];

    [openpanel setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];

    [openpanel setCanChooseDirectories:NO];

    [openpanel beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window
                      completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {

                          if (result == NSOKButton) {


                              [self doSomethingWithURLS:openpanel.URLs];


                          }


                      }];

}
```

so in your case the most important switch is `[openpanel setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];`

and you are going to want to make your object which presents the panel conform to `NSOpenSavePanelDelegate` (or some other object) then call

`[openpanel setDelegate:self];`

which has the following method available

`- (void)panelSelectionDidChange:(id)sender` where the sender is the panel

```
- (void)panelSelectionDidChange:(NSOpenPanel *)sender {

   NSArray *urlsSelected = sender.URLs;        

   NSMutableArray *final = [@[] mutableCopy];

    for (NSURL *url in urlsSelected) {

        [final addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\"",[url path]]];

    }

    [self.labelToPresentIn setStringValue:[final componentsJoinedByString:@","];

}
```

So each time the selection changes your label will change.

Thats a explicit answer to how to do what you are asking. Where you choose to present the label with that info is up to you. `NSOpenPanel` has a property `accessoryView` which allows you to glue an arbitrary view onto the panel. Like this…

So for a panel with multiple selection enabled.

[image: Open Accessory View]

As the other commenters mention don't try and make your OS X app look and act like Windows. Windows is Windows and OS X is OS X. Different OS's , Different UX.

What you are asking would look a bit weird in OS X. But maybe you have a better idea of what you want.

Try and observe how other OS X apps use the save and open panels.

Comment: but this still doesnt really answer my question, instead of a save dialog consider an open dialog OR user dragging multiple files onto an application is there any defined way of showing that those multiple files have been selected

Comment: the snippet shows you a simple NSOpenPanel implementation , the picture shows you a save panel with an accessory view which is what I was trying to demonstrate. And dragging files to an app window is a completely different question altogether , nothing to do with NSOpenPanel . Theres no standard way to demonstrate what files you have selected in a previously exhibited panel. Thats up to your UI decision.